# design and initialization of data in derived classes

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization

I have the following hierarchy:

```
  Base_class
      |
 Traits_class
      |
Concrete_class
```

Now the thing is that the data is contained in the `Base_class` (it needs to be there because the `Traits_class` has to have access to it. `Traits_class` is a class template that has different functionality depending on the template parameter passed (so I use partial template specialization for the different classes). Finally, at the lowest level, the `Concrete_class` is also a class template. I create instances of `Concrete_class` only.

Now the question is: I have written all constructors, the destructor and I have provided move semantics within the `Concrete_class`. That means that I do not call the base constructors, but I initialize the state directly in the derived classes.
Can someone point out if there is a problem with this? Only the destructor is declared in the `Base_class`, and declared as protected. Is there an evident flaw in this design?

Thanks for your insight!

**EDIT**

So I revised the design following Yakk's comment on the CRTP, and now I have

```
 Traits_class
      |
Concrete_class
```

I have also moved all data to the `Concrete_class`, and thanks to CRTP I can have access to it in the `Traits_class`. Something weird happened though, as I couldn't access the data in the `Traits_class` within the constructor of the `Traits_class`. I mean, I did access to it, but it seemed as if I was accessing ghost data, because I initialized the members in `Traits_class` (and even printed within the `Traits_class` constructor), but then just afterwards the class was empty. So I really don't understand what happened (I was const_casting the Traits_class into the Concrete_class to do this).

In the end, I wrote just static member functions in the `Traits_class` to initialize the members of the `Concrete_class`. I guess I could have used protected member functions to do the same thing (because I'm inheriting from `Traits_class`), but I believe it's the same thing.

If you have any further comments, please let me know. And thanks again for your C++ wisdom.

aa

Comment: "I do not call the base constructor" -- I think you do.  If you don't mention a constructor to call in the initializer list of a derived class constructor, you call the empty base constructor.  Your reasoning why data is in Base is not rock solid -- CRTP can give `Traits_class` access to data in a derived class.

Comment: Thanks Yakk for replying to my post. I'm familiar with CRTP, but then I would have to store a reference to the derived class, correct? Or there is another way to access the data?

Comment: `template<typename D> struct CRTP_example { D* self() { return static_cast<D*>(this); D const* self() const { return static_cast<D const*>(this); } int getx() const { return self()->x; } }; struct Derived:CRTP_example<Derived> { int x; Derived():x(7){} };` -- no reference storing involved.  You will want to `static_assert` that `CRTP_example<D>` is a base class of `D` as well.

Comment: I see, nice. You forgot to derive from D in CRTP_example, correct?

Comment: No, I did not forget.  :)  Create a `Derived`, then call `getx()`, and watch it return `7`.  `CRTP_example` doesn't derive from `D`, `D` derives from `CRTP_example`.  It is very curious, is it not?

Comment: And recurring... =)
Cool! Thakns Yakk!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your reasoning.  A constructor always initializes all base classes and nonstatic members (technically, a virtual base is initialized by the most-derived type and not by any of the other bases' constructors), so the Base_class will actually be initialized by its compiler-generated default constructor (or compiler-generated copy/move constructors if you're doing a copy or move), which will initialize all data members using their default (or copy/move) constructors.  You may later assign those members in the concrete class's constructors, but initialization has already occurred by this point.

Since the base class owns all the data members, it will actually be the base class that initializes all data members when a copy or move occurs.  If you write your own copy or move constructor in the most-derived class, you'll either need to invoke the base class's copy/move constructor in your initialization list or the data members will be default-constructed and you'll be forced to use a copy/move-assignment after the fact.  This is often inefficient and in some cases may be incorrect.  (For example, I've written classes that could be move-constructed, but could not be move-assigned because of slicing issues; if you had such a class in your Base_class as a data member, you couldn't implement move semantics solely in the Concrete_class.)

If you must initialize all the data members from Concrete_class, I recommend you provide a protected constructor in Base_class that takes all data members by value and moves them into its own data members, and provide a perfect-forwarding constructor in Traits_class (or inherit the base's constructor, if you are using a compiler with this support).  This allows the concrete class to specify the values for initializing the data members, but allows the base class to do the actual initialization.  It also allows the Base_class and Traits_class constructors access to the fully initialized data members (whereas otherwise they can only access the data members in their default-initialized state).

Here's an example:

`struct Base_class {
protected:
    Base_class( string s ) : s_( move(s) ) { }
    ~Base_class() = default;
    // Request copy/move, since we're declaring our own (protected) destructor:
    Base_class(Base_class const &) = default;
    Base_class(Base_class &&) = default;
    Base_class &operator=(Base_class const &) = default;
    Base_class &operator=(Base_class &&) = default;
     
    string s_;
};
 
template<int>
struct Traits_class : Base_class {
protected:
    template<typename... P>
    Traits_class( P &&p )
        : Base_class( forward<P>(p)... )
    { }
};
 
template<int I>
struct Concrete_class : Traits_class<I> {
    Concrete_class( char c )
        : Traits_class<I>( string( I, c ) )
    { }
};`

As a side-note, the data doesn't necessarily have to be in Base_class for Traits_class to be able to access it.  You could provide access via a protected virtual function if you don't mind the overhead of a virtual function call and if you don't need access within the constructors or destructor (which I'm assuming you don't, since currently the data members don't have their final values until after Concrete_class's constructor runs).  Or, to avoid the virtual call overhead, you could use the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern as @Yakk mentions.

**== RESPONSE TO EDIT IN ORIGINAL QUESTION ==**

The base class's constructor will run before the derived class's constructor, so if the data is stored in the derived class, it will be uninitialized in the base class's constructor (and already reclaimed in its destructor).  You can think of a constructor as taking an instance of base class and turning it into an instance of derived class (by initializing the derived part of the class, etc.), and as a special case, the constructor for a class with no base classes turns "nothing" (raw storage) into an instance of the class.

So, when your traits class constructor is running, it isn't yet a concrete derived class.  Consequently, accessing the derived class's data members or otherwise using the class as a derived class is illegal.  The language even enforces this for virtual functions; if you call a virtual function inside a base class's constructor or destructor, it will call the base version of the function.  Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Base {
  Base() { cout << "Base ctor\n"; v(); }
  ~Base() { v(); cout << "Base dtor\n"; }
protected:
  virtual void v() const { cout << "Base::v\n"; }
};

struct Derived : Base {
  Derived() { cout << "Derived ctor\n"; v(); }
  ~Derived() { v(); cout << "Derived dtor\n"; }
protected:
  virtual void v() const { cout << "Derived::v\n"; }
};

int main() { Derived d; }

/* Output:
Base ctor
Base::v
Derived ctor
Derived::v
Derived::v
Derived dtor
Base::v
Base dtor
*/
```